# getCookies() gets both the cookies and the session

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I have two servlets and the other servlet is supposed to output information from a cookie and from a session (instructions of our professor). The problem is, I tried using getCookies() to get cookies from the request object but it returns two objects the first one is with a name "JSESSIONID" and its accompanied hexadecimal code and the second one contains the cookie I created. Why did this happen? How would getCookie() solely return cookies?

Here's the code:

Servlet 1:

```
package com.telco.process;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConvertServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/Convert")
public class ConvertServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String num;
    private String telco;
    private HttpSession session;
    private RequestDispatcher rd;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String convertedNum = "";
        session = request.getSession();
        num = request.getParameter("number");
        telco = request.getParameter("telco");
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Display");

        Cookie cTelco = new Cookie("telco", telco);
        if (!(num.equals(null)) || !(num.equals("")))
        {
            for (byte i = 0; i < num.length(); i++)
            {
                switch(num.charAt(i))
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C': convertedNum += "2"; break;
                    case 'D': 
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F': convertedNum += "3"; break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H': 
                    case 'I': convertedNum += "4"; break;
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L': convertedNum += "5"; break;
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O': convertedNum += "6"; break;
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S': convertedNum += "7"; break;
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V': convertedNum += "8"; break;
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z': convertedNum += "9"; break;
                }
            }
            session.setAttribute("number", convertedNum);
            response.addCookie(cTelco);
        }
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Servlet 2:

```
package com.telco.process;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/Display")
public class DisplayNumber extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        Cookie ck[] = request.getCookies();
        System.out.println(ck[0].getValue());
        pw.println("The converted number is " + "-" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("number"));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSESSIONID is indeed a cookie, it is used to identify the session. A session is created on the server with an ID. The server sends a cookie with the ID to the browser (JSESSIONID). The browser then sends this JSESSIONID cookie to the server on each request, where the server uses it to map the request to the session.

**EDIT: Some example code to find a cookie:**

You should access your cookies only by name, not by index. Here is an example helper routine, you can use it like this (of course, check for `null` in a real program):

```
System.out.println(getCookieByName(request, "telco").getValue());


/**
 * Find a specific HTTP cookie in a request.
 * 
 * @param request
 *            The HTTP request object.
 * @param name
 *            The cookie name to look for.
 * @return The cookie, or <code>null</code> if not found.
 */
protected Cookie getCookieByName(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
    if (request.getCookies() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < request.getCookies().length; i++) {
        if (request.getCookies()[i].getName().equals(name)) {
            return request.getCookies()[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So how do I access my other cookie? By incrementing the cookie array index? And will the JSESSIONID still be present in other computers? Because in other examples, they only use index 0 to access their cookie.

Comment: You can not presume that your cookie is always at a certain index position of all cookies that are sent. I usually have a routine `Cookie getCookieByName(HttpServletRequest request, String name)` which iterates over all cookies and returns the cookie with the requested name.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know there was a method like that. Thanks.

Comment: there is no, I added some example code to my answer